# Native css mixins in sass

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm try to use native css mixins to construct another css mixins, but I'm  getting a follow error on compile:

```
$blue:            #29579b;

:root {
  --edi-blue: $blue;

  --text: {
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--edi-blue);
  }

  --text--bold: {
    @apply --text;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}

.someclass {
  @apply --text--bold;
}
```

**error:**

```
[16:48:58] Starting 'sass'...
[16:48:58] Finished 'sass' after 7.22 ms
Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
    src/shared/styles/sass/webcomponents-shared-styles.scss
Error: Illegal nesting: Only properties may be nested beneath properties.
        on line 11 of src/shared/styles/sass/webcomponents-shared-styles.scss
>>     @apply --text;
   ----^
```

**EDIT:**

Acording @vanloc, it cannot be done for the @apply rule as if you define it on a global scope (:root) it will always use variables only from that scope, so you cannot pass your local values.

So I'm try use the sass mixins to do the same thing:

```
@mixin --text() {
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--edi-blue);
}

:root {
  --edi-blue: $blue;

  --text: {
    @include --text;
  }

  --text--bold: {
    @include --text;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}

.someclass {
  @apply --text--bold;
}
```

the problem is the code generate:

```
:root {
  --text-font-style: normal;
  --text-font-stretch: normal;
  --text-text-align: center;
  --text-color: var(--edi-blue);
  --text--bold-font-style: normal;
  --text--bold-font-stretch: normal;
  --text--bold-text-align: center;
  --text--bold-color: var(--edi-blue);
  --text--bold-font-weight: bold; }

.someclass {
  @apply --text--bold; }
```

instead of:

```
:root {
  --text: {
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--edi-blue);
  }

  --text--bold: {
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--edi-blue);
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}

    .someclass {
      @apply --text--bold; }
```

Comment: Try taking --text--bold: outside of :root{}

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it cannot be done for the @apply rule as if you define it on a global scope (:root) it will always use variables only from that scope, so you cannot pass your local values.

It’s sad, but at least you can copy/paste your mixins to your “scopes” using e.g. preprocessor and than your local CSS variables would work.

Should be like that:

```
$blue:            #29579b;

:root {
  --edi-blue: $blue;

  --text: {
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--edi-blue);
  }
}

.text--bold {
   @apply --text;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: thx for the reply, that way the ```--text``` mixin isn't not generate correctilly. i updated the 1st post